# invalid short file name on Windows 7, on XP no problem

Tags: windows-installer

I'm installing GitExtensions207SetupComplete.msi on Windows 7
and getting an error:

"invalid short file name username.user".

Using the SAME MSI on Windows XP works just fine.

any hints, tools to fix the error or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is simple go to the following registry location in regedit: 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Microsoft/Windows/Explorer/User Shell` Folders

Here you should change the personal registry key from `\\<domain>\profiles$\<username>` to `%USERPROFILE%\<username>`.

This should fix the error.